# When namespacing I receive a "cannot GET error" displayed in browser

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, socket.io

I'm using namespaces to differentiate between version of my socket.io chat app, and I'm having trouble with a "cannot GET error displayed in browser."

I plan on continually updating a chat app I made in a basic socket.io tutorial, and I want to be able to launch any version of it at any time. I'm going to do this by the use of namespaces. When I launch my app in browser at the location myserverlocation/v0.0.1 to access version 0.0.1 of my app, I get an error that states cannot GET '/v0.0.1'.

This is my server code:

```
var app = require('express')(),
    server = require('http').Server(app),
    io = require('socket.io').listen(server),
    chat = io.of('/v0.0.1');

server.listen(80);

// routing
app.get('/', function (req, res) {
    res.sendfile(__dirname + '/index.html');
});

// usernames which are currently connected to the chat
var usernames = {};

chat.on('connection', function (socket) {

    // when the client emits 'sendchat', this listens and executes
    socket.on('sendchat', function (data) {
        // we tell the client to execute 'updatechat' with 2 parameters
        io.sockets.emit('updatechat', socket.username, data);
    });

    // when the client emits 'adduser', this listens and executes
    socket.on('adduser', function(username) {
        // we store the username in the socket session for this client
        socket.username = username;
        // add the client's username to the global list
        usernames[username] = username;
        // echo to client they've connected
        socket.emit('updatechat', 'SERVER', 'you have connected');
        // echo globally (all clients) that a person has connected
        socket.broadcast.emit('updatechat', 'SERVER', username + ' has connected');
        // update the list of users in chat, client-side
        io.sockets.emit('updateusers', usernames);
    });

    // when the user disconnects.. perform this
    socket.on('disconnect', function() {
        // remove the username from global usernames list
        delete usernames[socket.username];
        // update list of users in chat, client-side
        io.sockets.emit('updateusers', usernames);
        // echo globally that this client has left
        socket.broadcast.emit('updatechat', 'SERVER', socket.username + ' has disconnected');
    });
});
```

And this is my client code:

```
<script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
    var socket = io.connect('myserverlocation');

    var chat = socket.of('/v0.0.1');

    // on connection to server, ask for user's name with an anonymous callback
    chat.on('connect', function(){
        // call the server-side function 'adduser' and send one parameter (value of prompt)
        chat.emit('adduser', prompt("What's your name?"));
    });

    // listener, whenever the server emits 'updatechat', this updates the chat body
    chat.on('updatechat', function(username, data) {
        $('#conversation').append('<b>' + username + ':</b> ' + data + '<br>');
    });

    // listener, whenever the server emits 'updateusers', this updates the username list
    chat.on('updateusers', function(data) {
        $('#users').empty();
        $.each(data, function(key, value) {
            $('#users').append('<div>' + key + '</div>');
        });
    });

    // on load of page
    $(function(){
        // when the client clicks SEND
        $('#datasend').click( function() {
            var message = $('#data').val();
            $('#data').val('');
            // tell server to execute 'sendchat' and send along one parameter
            chat.emit('sendchat', message);
        });

        // when the client hits ENTER on their keyboard
        $('#data').keypress(function(e) {
            if(e.which == 13) {
                $(this).blur();
                $('#datasend').focus().click();
            }
        });
    });

</script>
<div style="float:left;width:100px;border-right:1px solid black;height:300px;padding:10px;overflow:scroll-y;">
    <b>USERS</b>
    <div id="users"></div>
</div>
<div style="float:left;width:300px;height:250px;overflow:scroll-y;padding:10px;">
    <div id="conversation"></div>
    <input id="data" style="width:200px;" />
    <input type="button" id="datasend" value="send" />
</div>
```

My chat app works fine without the use of namespaces, at myserverlocation/. I cannot figure out why I keep getting this error. After some investigation I think my usage of io.of() is incorrect, but I cannot seem to fix the problem. I'm not sure if my problem lies in the server code, the client code, or both.

Edit: After more investigation, I think my problem lies in the follow segment of code (though I could be mistaken):

```
app.get('/', function (req, res) {
        res.sendfile(__dirname + '/index.html');
});
```

Edit2: The problem did in fact lie in the code segment above. I should have been sending my whole /Chat directory as static content instead of using res.sendfile() to send one file. I will formally answer my own question when stackoverflow lets me (I have to wait 8 hours to answer my own question).

Comment: Not totally sure of this, but it's possible that it doesn't like the dots in your namespace? Either way [Apigee recommends](https://blog.apigee.com/detail/restful_api_design_tips_for_versioning): Use a simple ordinal number - v1, v2, and so on. Don't use the dot notation like v1.2 because it implies a granularity of versioning that doesn't work well with APIs--it's an interface not an implementation.

Comment: I just tried changing the version name to v1 and the problem still remained. I will take your advice for naming versions in a simple manner in the future, however.

Comment: I fixed my own problem, but apparently I can't answer my own question until 8 hours after it was posted lol. I will post my answer as soon as I can in case anyone else has the problem in the future. The problem was my usage of res.sendfile().

Comment: I appreciate that you will be answering your own question. It sounds like you really get what Stack Overflow is all about. That being the case, welcome to Stack Overflow :D

Comment: Thanks, Stack Overflow looks like a great community :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to find what my problem was. The problem lied in the following section of code:

```
app.get('/', function (req, res) {
        res.sendfile(__dirname + '/index.html');
});
```

I was sending one particular file upon connection to my server, when I should be sending my entire /Chat directory as static content. This way, I can chose what version of my chat app I would like to launch. I managed to do this by changing a few lines of code in my server code:

```
var express = require('express'),
    app = express(),
    server = require('http').createServer(app),
    io = require('socket.io').listen(server);

server.listen(80);

// Chat directory
app.use(express.static('/home/david/Chat'));
```